# Button handlers in XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have simple WPF layout task and looking to avoid code-behind if possible.

I have two panels left and right. When I am colapsing left panel - right panel gets stretched ...
this is my xaml:

```
        <Grid Name="gridContainer">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Grid.Column="0" Name="leftPanel" >
                <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

            <GridSplitter Name="leftSplitter" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Label Content="... Clien Area .. Has to Stretch vertically and horizontally" Margin="10"></Label>
                <Button Click="LeftButton_Click" Margin="10">Close Left Panel</Button>                    
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

This is code-behind:

```
    private void LeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(leftPanel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
        {
            gridContainer.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = GridLength.Auto;
            leftPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            leftSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            gridContainer.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = GridLength.Auto;
            leftPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            leftSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

I am wondering, are there any way to avoid the code behind here? and acomplish this task in XAML only?

Thanks for advice

Comment: As the saying goes, "just because you can, doesn't necessarily mean you should" ;) In all seriousness though, MVVM could really help you out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this without code-behind.

First we need to set up a specific styling that will allow us to toggle the `visibility` for the `StackPanel`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="panelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Next we do some minor modifications in your original code.

Add the styling and bind the `Tag` of the `StackPanel` to the `Button`.

```
<StackPanel Background="Aqua" Style="{StaticResource panelStyle}" Tag="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" Grid.Column="0" Name="leftPanel" >
```

Change the `Button` to a `ToggleButton` and assign it a name.

```
<ToggleButton Name="myButton" Margin="10">Close Left Panel</ToggleButton>
```

It should look something like this ones you are done.

```
<Grid Name="gridContainer">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Style="{StaticResource panelStyle}" Tag="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" Grid.Column="0" Name="leftPanel" >
        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" TextWrapping="Wrap">Left Hand Side</TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>

    <GridSplitter Name="leftSplitter" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="... Clien Area .. Has to Stretch vertically and horizontally" Margin="10"></Label>
        <ToggleButton Name="myButton" Margin="10">Close Left Panel</ToggleButton>           
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have to say though that I highly recommend that you look into using the MVVM pattern as well. In this case it's fine as it's pretty simple, but if you start adding more logic you should use some more advanced logic, or at least move this into a custom dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You could eliminate your code behind using Commanding and the MVVM pattern. You could have Visibility properties in your view model that would be data bound to your XAML elements.

Then using commanding you could route your click event to a command in your view model. Here's a quick post on solid commanding patterns in WPF. 
 [What is the accepted pattern for WPF commanding in MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908603/what-is-the-accepted-pattern-for-wpf-commanding-in-mvvm)

Using this approach you could eliminate your XAML code behind as well as set yourself up nicely to unit test your view model's behavior when the command is executed.

Comment: thanks for answer. But question was not about MVVM, it was more about WPF and XAML. These kind of tasks has to be accoplished in the XAML or code-behind (View part). I can't clasify this task as presentation Logic and move it to the View Model, is more interaction logic and has to live in View.

Comment: That's cool, I just wanted to bring up the pattern and mention that as a best practice it helps to be able to unit test logic that says "if X happens then Y should happen depending on what the value of X is". Best of luck